# How does cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE convert 16 bit images to 8 bit (OpenCV python)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am importing images in python using OpenCV.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

The image is a 16 bit *.png* or *.tif*, and is converted to 8 bit by `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` (as expected). I am happy that OpenCV converts my image. I am aware that I can use `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` if I want a 16bit image.

I just want to know **how** OpenCV is converting my image from 16 to 8 bit. E.g. via typical normalisation, or in some other way that might saturate pixels? For my downstream problems it is more important that the general range is preserved.

I have checked the OpenCV documentation and cannot find an explanation for this. I cannot find a similar question.

EDIT: My images are single channel.

Comment: I would guess it will compress the rgb channel range 0 to max value to 0-255, so you will loose some dynamic range.

Comment: I suspect it simply divides the 16-bit image gray values by 257. For 16-bit images, the max value is 65535 and for 8-bit images it is 255. 65535/257 = 255

Comment: @fmw42 more likely to divide by 256 than 257.  If you divide by 257, the only way to get 255 is to start with 65535 so 255 will be under-represented in the output.

Comment: Also it's possible that there's a gamma conversion going from 16 bits to 8.  16 bits is enough to encode everything linearly, but 8 bits absolutely requires some kind of gamma to make everything fit.

Answer (score -1):

The uint 16 image ( or the 16 bit image ) used values from 0 to 2^16-1, while the uint8 images ( or the 8 bit image ) uses a range from, 0 to 2^8-1 only.
If you just cast the original values to uint8, the saturation will destroy a lot of information.
This is seen in the form of quality degradation .
This happens due to bit depth .

---

“Bit-depth” determines the smallest changes you can make, relative to some range of values. If our scale is brightness from pure black to pure white, then the 4 values we get from a 2-bit number would include: black, dark midtones, light midtones, and white. This is a pretty lumpy scale and not very useful for a photograph. But if we have enough bits, we have enough gray values to make what appears to be a perfectly smooth gradient from black to white.

Here’s an example comparing a black to white gradient at different bit depths. The embedded image here is just an example, click here to see the full resolution image in the JPEG2000 format with bit depths up to 14-bits. Depending on the quality of your monitor, you can probably only display differences up to 8-10 bits.

---

[image: View this picture for a better understanding]

---

All software designs use and implement the same process.